# Blazor - Problem with EventCallback of multiple instances of same component

Tags: c#, asp.net, components, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I'm having some problems with my C# Blazor App.

I've got a simple component that runs a js file, the js file after some operations will call the **UpdateLocalizationData** method. The method will populate the **Place** object and invoke the EventCallback. This is the component **AddressComponent**:

```
@page "/AddressComponent"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime


<input id="@Id" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Search address" />

@code {

    private static Place PlaceToUse { get; set; } = new Place();

    [Parameter] 
    public EventCallback<Place> OnPlaceSelected { get; set; }

    [Parameter] 
    public string Id { get; set; }


    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initAutocomplete", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), Id);
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void UpdateLocalizationData(string lat, string lon)
    {    
        PlaceToUse.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        PlaceToUse.Latitudine = lat;
        PlaceToUse.Longitudine = lon;

        OnPlaceSelected.InvokeAsync(PlaceToUse);
    }
}
```

Then i call the component in two different razor components. **PageA.razor**:

```
<AddressComponent OnPlaceSelected="HandlePlace" Id="addressA"></AddressComponent>

@code{
    private ItemA ItemATest { get; set; } = new ItemA()
    private void HandlePlace(Place place)
    {
        ItemATest.Place = place;
    }
}
```

**PageB.razor**:

```
<AddressComponent OnPlaceSelected="HandlePlace" Id="addressB"></AddressComponent>

@code{
    private ItemB ItemBTest { get; set; } = new ItemB()
    private void HandlePlace(Place place)
    {
        ItemBTest.Place = place;
    }
}
```

Both components (PageA and PageB) are then called in the main page.

My problem is that when the **EventCallback** method of the **AddressComponent** in **PageA** is triggered, it triggers the method **HandlePlace** of **PageB**.
From what i've understood, the parameters of the component (such as the EventCallback) are getting replaced everytime the component is instantiated, thus resulting in  the Eventcallback of only the last component being triggered.
How can i solve this? Am i using the wrong approach?

Comment: I think `@page "/AddressComponent"` is not needed for a Component but that may not help. Can you add how PageA and PageB are embedded to your App? Is it Blazor WA or Blazor Server?

Comment: Thanks, i removed it. It is a Blazor Server app. 
For the 2 components, i just call them in an empty page

Comment: So PageA and PageB are embedded to another page? Not accessed via Navigation?

Comment: Yep, i just call<PageA></PageA> <PageB></PageB> inside a .razor page

Comment: `UpdateLocalizationData` is called from JavaScript, may it be called on all instances? May be post the javaScript code calling `UpdateLocalizationData`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the JS method that you call using InvokeVoidAsync.
The first call sets the instance to PageA, the second call overwrites the instance to PageB. So all calls made from the JS function will be done on PageB